# Insert to Oracle Database with cx_Oracle python 2.7

Tags: python, oracle, sql-insert, cx-oracle

I connected to my oracle database with cx_Oracle, had good connection and read needed data from base. Then tried to insert something in base and failed.

```
try:
   print uid2 + "/" + pwd2 + "@" + service1
   dconn1 = cx_Oracle.connect(uid2 + "/" + pwd2 + "@" + service1)
except:
  pass
print dconn1
ver = dconn1.version.split(".")
print ver
cur = dconn1.cursor()
pdb.set_trace()
rows=[("NET-CI99999")]
sql_test='insert into Device2M1 (logical_name) values (:1)'
sql_test_2='insert into Device2M1 (logical_name) values ("NET-CI99999")'
#cur.prepare(sql_insert)
#cur.execute(sql_test_2)
cur.prepare(sql_test)
cur.executemany(None,rows)
dconn1.commit()
cur.execute("select logical_name,serial_no_,location,id,updated_by,contact_name,istatus,subtype,user_id,sysmodtime,sysmoduser,title,email,extension,ip_address,mac_address,updated_by, ig_fqdn,ig_domain,ig_model,ig_vendor,ig_inventory_numb,ig_network_equip,ig_name,ig_asset_tag,ig_it_asset_id,ig_it_asset_created,ig_registrator  from Device2M1 where logical_name='NET-CI13681'")

for result in cur:
    for i in  result:
#        pdb.set_trace()
        print i
cur.close()
dconn1.close()
```

Part of the code with selections worked well, when try do just cur.execute for insertion console hang and make no replay, when try to do something with executemany have an error "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: неверное имя/номер переменной (wrong name/number of the variable)". Any idea about what is this and what could I do for proper working of the code?

Comment: Check the tutorial https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial for an example of executemany()

Comment: I inserted my credentials into https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/bind_insert.py and got the same result: ORA-01036

Comment: Cut down the testcase until you can share it, and also the create table statement so we can easily see it.